# Mostrar consulta de 2 tablas diferentes en un dataTable de Primefaces

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces, mybatis

Trabajo en una aplicación con JSF , Primefaces , MySQL y la persistencia con MyBatis.
Necesito recuperar la información de 2 tablas de una BD(Toda la información de una y toda o parte de la otra) y mostrarlas en un mismo p:dataTable.

Nota: Para cada tabla ya está  funcionando mostrar los datos en su propio dataTable.
Consultando encontré que puedo hacerlo con la etiqueta “association”(MyBatis) manejando join en un resulmap como lo muestro más adelante, pero no encuentro *como pasar estos datos a un dataTable de primefaces en JSF*.

La pregunta es: ¿que debo agregar a la pagina xhtml donde tengo el p: dataTable  o a la clase pojo, y/o  a la clase del bean, para visualizar los datos de las 2 tablas?.

Esto es lo que tengo en la BD :

- Estudiantes (Tiene PRIMARY KEY (`idEstudiante`)

-Matriculas  (Tiene  PRIMARY KEY (`idMatricula`)
         FOREIGN KEY (`idEstudiante`)

-Así es como en un DataTable recupero los datos de la tabla matriculas(algo similar funciona para  la tabla Estudiantes y deberá ser con algunos cambios pienso yo, para  la asociación de las 2 tablas)

```
<p:dataTable value="#{matriculasbean.matricula}" var="aux"
paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" editable="true"
style="margin-bottom:20px" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%"
rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

<p:column headerText="Id Estudiante">
    <h:outputText value="#{aux.idEstudiante}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Grado">
    <h:outputText value="#{aux.grado}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Curso">
    <h:outputText value="#{aux.nombreCurso}" />
</p:column>
```

-Pojo para Matriculas:

```
   public class Matriculas {
        private int idMatricula;
        private int idEstudiante;   
        private String grado;
        private String nombreCurso;
        private Date fechaMatricula;
        private Double costoMatricula;  

        public Matriculas() {               

        }

    // Getters y Setters
```

-Pojo para Estudiantes:

```
 public class Estudiantes {

        private int idEstudiante;
        private String nombreEstudiante;
        private String primerApellidoE;
        private String segundoApellidoE;    
        private String tipoDocumento;

    public Estudiantes() {

    }
    // Getters y Setters
```

-La clase java beans desde donde llamo el mapper para la consulta de las 2 tablas:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Matriculasbean {

    private Matriculas matriculas;

  public Matriculasbean() {

        matriculas= new Matriculas();
    }

  public List<Matriculas> getMatriEstuNombre(){
    System.out.println("está en getMatriEstuNombre");
    List<Matriculas> lista = null;

    SqlSession session = new MyUtil().getSession();

    if (session != null) {              
        try { lista = session.selectList("Coleg.selectMatriculasestu");

    } finally {
        session.close();                }

    }else {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        return lista;       
    }   
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo de acuerdo a lo que he investigado, utilizando Mapper y resulmap con MyBatis en una relación uno a uno en el fichero xml de mapeo  para hacer el join entre las 2 tablas:

-El Select para la consulta:

```
  <select id="selectMatriculasestu" parameterType="int" 
    resultMap="ResulMatricula">
           select
                    M.idEstudiante as idEstudiante,
                    M.idMatricula as idMatricula,
                    M.grado as grado,
                    M.nombreCurso as nombreCurso,
                    M.fechaMatricula as fechaMatricula,
                    M.costoMatricula as costoMatricula,
                    E.nombreEstudiante as nombreEstudiante,
                    E.primerApellidoE as  primerApellidoE,
                    E.segundoApellidoE as segundoApellidoE
                    E.tipoDocumento as tipoDocumento 
    from Matriculas M left outer join Estudiantes E on M.idEstudiante = 
    E.idEstudiante where M.idEstudiante = #{idEstudiante}
    </select>
```

-Mapeo:

```
<resultMap  id="ResulMatricula" type="Matriculas">
   <id column="idEstudiante" property="idEstudiante" javaType="int"/> 
   <result column="idMatricula" property="idMatricula" javaType="int"/>
   <result column="grado" property="grado" javaType="string"/>
   <result column="nombreCurso" property="nombreCurso" javaType="string"/>
   <result column="fechaMatricula" property="fechaMatricula" javaType="date"/>
   <result column="costoMatricula" property="costoMatricula" javaType="double"/>

   <association property="Estudiantes" javaType="Estudiantes" resultMap="ResulEstudiantes" /> 
</resultMap> 

<resultMap  id="ResulEstudiantes" type="Estudiantes">           
   <id column="idEstudiante" property="idEstudiante" javaType="int"/>
     <result column="nombreEstudiante" property="nombreEstudiante" javaType="string"/>
     <result column="primerApellidoE" property="primerApellidoE" javaType="string"/>
     <result column="segundoApellidoE" property="segundoApellidoE" javaType="string"/>
     <result column="tipoDocumento" property="tipoDocumento" javaType="int"/>

    </resultMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arenas:

Nota que estás trabajando con un ORM, por lo que deberías ser capaz de pedirle a cada entity el objeto que represena la clase referenciada o la lista de objetos que lo referencian a él. Algo como esto

```
    Matriculas matricula = findMatricula('1') // asumiendo que tienes un método que 
    te devuelve una matríclula según su id.
    Estudiante estudiante = matricula.getEstudianteFK();

    // También es válido el caso contrario
    List<Matricula> list = estudiante.getMatriculas(); //esto debería devolver  la 
    lista de matrículas del estudiante
```

Luego en un datatable podrías tener algo como esto, aprobechando que matrícula tiene el id del estudiante:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{matriculasbean.matricula}" var="aux"
paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" editable="true"
style="margin-bottom:20px" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%"
rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

<p:column headerText="Id Estudiante">
<h:outputText value="#{aux.idEstudiante}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Grado">
<h:outputText value="#{aux.grado}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Curso">
<h:outputText value="#{aux.nombreCurso}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Un dato del estudiante asociado a la matrícula aux">
<h:outputText value="#{aux.estudianteFK.atributoDelEstudiante}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Otro dato del estudiante asociado a la matrícula aux">
<h:outputText value="#{aux.estudianteFK.otroAtributoDelEstudiante}" />
</p:column>
```